# why does this wget incantation not retrieve the desired files

Tags: linux, terminal, wget, https

I am currtently trying to download data from https server using wget. There are plenty of subfolders and files but only one file extension (*.raw) is interesting me. (Parent folders are not desired)

These command have been tried :

```
 wget --recursive --no-directories --no-parent --level 10 --accept "raw" --execute robots=off https://cptc-xfer.uis.georgetown.edu/publicData/Phase_II_Data/TCGA_Ovarian_Cancer_S_026/
```

and

```
wget --mirror --convert-links --adjust-extension --page-requisites --no-parent https://cptc-xfer.uis.georgetown.edu/publicData/Phase_II_Data/TCGA_Ovarian_Cancer_S_026/
```

However, entering the same command with one of the directory containing files of interest is working (but not desired as it should be done manually)

```
wget --recursive --no-directories --no-parent --level 10 --accept .raw --execute robots=off https://cptc-xfer.uis.georgetown.edu/publicData/Phase_II_Data/TCGA_Ovarian_Cancer_S_026/TCGA_09-1664-01A_61-2094-01A_25-1312-01A_Proteome_JHUZ_20130802/TCGA_09-1664-01A_61-2094-01A_25-1312-01A_Proteome_JHUZ_20130802_raw/
```

Any idea how to formulate the command to get the files ?
Thanks by advance,
Vivian

Answer (score 0):

This simple edit of the first command solves the problem.

```
wget --recursive -nd --no-parent --level 10 --accept "*.raw" --execute robots=off https://cptc-xfer.uis.georgetown.edu/publicData/Phase_II_Data/TCGA_Ovarian_Cancer_S_026/
```